# LINQ to SQL query using "NOT IN"

Tags: sql, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Can LINQ to SQL query using **NOT IN**?

e.g., SELECT au_lname, state FROM authors WHERE state NOT IN ('CA', 'IN', 'MD')

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
    List<string> states = new List<string> { "CA", "IN", "MD" };
    var q = from a in authors
            where !states.Contains(a.state)
            select new { a.au_lname, a.state };
```

or

```
   var q = authors.Where( a => !states.Contains( a.state ) )
                  .Select( a => new { a.au_lname, a.state } );
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with Contains:

```
       var states = new[]  {"CA", "IN", "MD"};
       var query = db.Authors.Where(x => !states.Contains(x.state));
```

Answer (score 7):

here's an example:

```
NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
dc.Log = Console.Out;
var query =
    from c in dc.Customers
    where !(from o in dc.Orders
            select o.CustomerID)
           .Contains(c.CustomerID)
    select c;
foreach (var c in query) Console.WriteLine( c );
```

Comment: There's not really need to do the subquery - the Contains / !Contains will work within the context of the main query.

Answer (score 4):

Yes!

Here's an example from code we already had written:

```
            List<long> badUserIDs = new List { 10039309, 38300590, 500170561 };
            BTDataContext dc = new BTDataContext();
            var items = from u in dc.Users
                        where !badUserIDs.Contains(u.FbUserID)
                        select u;
```

The generated SQL turns out to be:

`{SELECT [t0].[UserID], [t0].[FbUserID], [t0].[FbNetworkID], [t0].[Name], 
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [t0]
WHERE NOT ([t0].[FbUserID] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2))
}`