# LINQ to SQL WHERE "IN"

Tags: linq-to-sql

How ia can write query with IN. I want write query

```
Products.Where(x=>x.CategoryId = {4,5,6....})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Products.Where(x => arrayOfIDs.Contains(x.CategoryId));
```

Answer (score 1):

[LINQ to SQL query using "NOT IN"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344478/linq-to-sql-query-using-not-in)