# I am trying to convert a SQL Query to Linq to Entities using "Not IN"

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities

I have a SQL query (stored procedure) that I am having a hard time trying to write in Linq using "NOT IN".

This is the SQL query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAvailableRoles2User]
    @Id nvarchar(128)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT name 
    FROM Role 
    WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT t3.Name
                       FROM [User] t1 
                       JOIN [UserRole] t2 ON t1.Id = t2.UserId 
                       JOIN [Role] t3 ON t2.RoleId = t3.RoleId
                       WHERE t1.Id = @Id)
END
```

And here is what I am trying to do in in my MVC action Method

```
var result = (from x in db.Users
              join y in db.IdentityUserRoles on x.Id equals y.UserId
              join z in db.Roles on y.RoleId equals z.Id 
              where x.Id == id 
              select z.Name);
```

Could some explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq to Sql query using "not in"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344478/linq-to-sql-query-using-not-in)

Comment: I looked at that but I have two where clauses and can't figure out how to write it with the two

Comment: @PsyChotic, the count of `Where` conditions is not important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got your relationships and such set up right in Entity Framework (and assuming a Role's Name is unique), it should be as simple as:

```
from role in db.Roles
where !role.Users.Any()
select role.Name
```

If you *don't* have the relationships set up so that your Role entities have a Users property like this, then it'll be a bit more complicated. However, if you've got good enough data integrity in place that there are no IdentityUserRole entries without a corresponding User, then there's no need to involve the Users table at all:

```
from role in db.Roles
where !db.IdentityUserRoles.Any(iur => iur.Name == role.Name)
select role.Name
```